# SCCM keeps working even after closing it

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, sccm

We have some test workstations that, during some times, need to keep descynched from SCCM deployments. For that, we continuously run the following script on these machines.

```
net stop CcmExec
Taskkill /IM CmRcService.exe /F
```

At any given time, I verify TaskManager and Services and see that SCCM isn't running. Still, apps we install for testing and homologation are uninstalled and replaced by homologated outdated ones.

Am I missing something to disable SCCM?

Comment: In CM Client, there is a feature which automatically evaluate client health, including performing checks  to make sure that key areas such as prerequisites, dependent services and WMI are all functioning. I don't know why you want to disable CM agent. But you can read this thread to disable auto evaluation: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanm/2012/12/20/configuration-manager-client-health-disable-automatic-remediation/.  If you let me know what you're trying to do, maybe there will be better options than just disable CM agent.

Comment: My department needs to test applications to homologate them to be deployed to all PCs. But due to political issues we're unable to talk to department responsible to SCCM to disable it on our testing PCs. We need to install not homologated apps to approve them, but SCCM keeps uninstalling them and installing outdated versions. So we need to disable SCCM on these PCs so we can do our jobs. Yes, sometimes politics is opposite to reasoning.

Comment: OK, so it will be better if there are testing PCs which are not managed by SCCM (don't install SCCM agent). Then in the future you'll not have the problem again. For now, if you're not able to do from SCCM management side, then please try to see if above helps to stop SCCM from being fixing itself.

Comment: Thanks. I did the change in Registry, now I'm seeing if it changes anything.